# How to have a matrix of 3 lines, but with slightly shift of 0.33 line so as to write 2 lines, while the?

Tags: matrices

How to change the following tex code in order that the "(" and ")"
of the matrix are of same size as the "(" and ")" of the \nu vectors ?

So far, I do :

```
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\nu_e\\
\nu_{\mu}\\
\nu_{\tau}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\vspace{0.33cm}PMNS}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\vspace{0.33cm}matrix}\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\nu_1\\
\nu_2\\
\nu_3
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
```

but this is not satisfactory since the parentheses of the matrix extend too much on the top and the bottom.

[image]

My goal is to have this style (grabed on the web):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

zzzz
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_e\\
\nu_{\mu}\\
\nu_{\tau}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathit{PMNS}\\[1\normalbaselineskip]
\mathit{matrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_1\\
\nu_2\\
\nu_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}


zzzz
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_e\\
\nu_{\mu}\\
\nu_{\tau}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\noalign{\vspace{.4\normalbaselineskip}}
\mathit{PMNS}\\[.2\normalbaselineskip]
\mathit{matrix}\\
\noalign{\vspace{.4\normalbaselineskip}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_1\\
\nu_2\\
\nu_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many put the P of PMNS in parentheses because Pontecorvo really did not use a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat would you like the parens to be as big as the other 6, for consistency:-)

Comment: You can do that but then some may take this as the parity transformation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to guess dimensions: just use a phantom in the middle matrix.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix} \nu_{e} \\ \nu_{\mu} \\ \nu_{\tau} \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\vphantom{\begin{pmatrix} \nu_{e} \\ \nu_{\mu} \\ \nu_{\tau} \end{pmatrix}}
\begin{matrix} \text{PNMS} \\ \text{matrix} \end{matrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \nu_{1} \\ \nu_{2} \\ \nu_{3} \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_e\\
\nu_{\mu}\\
\nu_{\tau}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{c}
 PMNS\bigstrut[t] \\
 matrix \bigstrut[b]
 \end{tabular}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_1\\
\nu_2\\
\nu_3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you both : I was exactly looking for the variante 2 of David, or the variante of Bernard. Thank you so much.